# make div width increase with content

Tags: css

I have 2 divs aligned one below the other. These are nested inside another div as

```
<div id="site-wrapper">
 <div id="user1"><div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is as

```
#site-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

How do we adjust the user1 and footer so that when the content of user1 expands the site-wrapper expands automatically

Comment: Doesn't that happen already with the code you've provided?  Do you have styles for user1 and/or footer?

Comment: sorry I want the site-wrapper (outer div) to expand as the inner divs increase in height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the height of the wrapper explicitly to 100%.

Remove that property and you will see what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use width in site-wrapper, instead use min-width

Use overflow:hidden in site-wrapper, it should expand

Answer (score 1):

change the parameters of `height: %` to `height: px`. This will expand as required!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while.
But this perfectly worked for me.
Try :

```
#user1 { 
    width: fit-content;
}
```